# ¿Qué es una Consulta Anidada?

Tags: sql

He visto preguntas en el sitio sobre algun problema con lo que dicen que es una consulta anidada, pero no me queda claro qué es, apenas vengo comenzando a conocer SQL. Si pudieran darme un ejemplo, lo agradecería mucho

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es una subconsulta, una consulta que se lanza dentro de otra consulta.
Por ejemplo:
`select nombre, edad from Jugadores where NomEquipo in(select Nombre from Equipos where titulos=2);`
Esto nos da el nombre y edad de los jugadores cuyos equipos tengan dos titulos. Primero se resuelve la subconsulta o consulta anidada dando los nombres de los aquipos que tienen dos titulos y luego este dato se compara con la tabla jugadores resolviendo la otra consulta.

Hay problemas con ellas porque son lentas al tener que resolver una por una cada consulta, por eso se recomienda usar consultas multitabla que hacen la consulta directamente en mas de una tabla a la vez.
Multitabla seria algo asi..
`select Jugadores.nombre, Jugadores.edad from Jugadores inner join Equipos on Jugadores.NomEquipo = Equipos.Nombre where Equipos.titulos=2;`

Comment: podrías poner la versión "consulta multitabla" equivalente a la subconsulta?

Comment: excelente respuesta Dios te bendiga