# Join 5 tablas con 2 tablas pivote en mysql, sql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, join

favor me pueden ayudar con el siguiente dilema, tengo 5 tablas

```
Obra ID(PK)
Vivienda ID(PK), id_obra(FK), id_tipologia(FK)
Tipologia ID(PK)
PartidaTipologia ID(PK), id_partida(FK), id_tipologia(FK)
Partida ID(PK), id_obra
```

Las tablas Vivienda y `partida_tipologia` son tablas `pivote` y necesito hacer una consulta donde pueda sacar los datos de estas tablas relacionadas

[image: Estas son las 5 tablas que quiero relacionar en un join]

pude hacer el join de estas 2 pivote pero no logro hacer la consulta para enlazarlas 
Join de la tabla pivote partida_tipologia

```
<code>

SELECT * FROM
    partida_tipologia
INNER JOIN
    partida_productividad ON partida_tipologia.id_partida = partida_productividad.id
INNER JOIN
    tipologia_productividad ON partida_tipologia.id_tipologia = tipologia_productividad.id
</code>

Join de la tabla vivienda
<code>
SELECT * FROM
    vivienda
INNER JOIN
    obra ON vivienda.id_obra = obra.id
INNER JOIN
    tipologia_productividad ON vivienda.id_tipologia = tipologia_productividad.id
</code>
```

Saludos!!

Edición ... 
Probe ese codigo que me enviaste y lo deje de la siguiente manera

`SELECT
    obra.id AS id_obra,
    tipologia_productividad.id AS id_tipologia,
    vivienda.id AS id_vivienda,
    partida_tipologia.id AS id_partidaTipologia,
    partida_productividad.id AS id_partida_productividad
FROM
    obra, tipologia_productividad, vivienda, partida_tipologia, partida_productividad
WHERE
    vivienda.id_obra = obra.id AND
    vivienda.id_tipologia = tipologia_productividad.id AND
    partida_tipologia.id_partida = partida_productividad.id AND
    partida_tipologia.id_tipologia = tipologia_productividad.id AND
    vivienda.id_tipologia = partida_tipologia.id_tipologia`

pero me salto la duda si puedo hacer lo mismo con un select anidado, tengo esta consulta que me da
como resultado las tipologia_productividad.id (un numero identificador de la tabla)

`SELECT tipologia_productividad.id FROM
    ((partida_tipologia
INNER JOIN
    partida_productividad ON partida_tipologia.id_partida = partida_productividad.id)
INNER JOIN
    tipologia_productividad ON partida_tipologia.id_tipologia = tipologia_productividad.id)
WHERE
    partida_tipologia.estado=1;`

y tengo esta otra consulta donde quiero anidar el otro select donde la tipologia_productividad.id sea identica y obtener asi todos los datos

`SELECT * FROM
    ((vivienda
INNER JOIN
    tipologia_productividad ON vivienda.id_tipologia = tipologia_productividad.id)
INNER JOIN
    obra ON vivienda.id_obra = obra.id)`

Answer (score 1):

Creo que seria asi:

```
select Vivienda.ID as id_Vivienda, Vivienda.id_obra,
       Vivienda.id_tipologia, PartidaTipologia.ID as 
       id_PartidaTipologia,
       PartidaTipologia.id_partida from Obra 
inner join 
      Vivienda on Obra.id = Vivienda.id_obra 
inner join
      Tipoogia on Vivienda.id_tipoogia = Tipologia.ID 
inner join
      PartidaTipologia on Tipologia.ID = PartidaTipologia.id_tipologia 
inner join
      Partida on PartidaTipologia.id_partida = Partida.ID
```

Respecto a lo de hacer una consuta anidada podrias hacer algo asi, aunque como ves solo nos daria los datos de una de las tablas.

```
SELECT * FROM
    vivienda
INNER JOIN
    Tipologia ON vivienda.id_tipologia = Tipologia.ID)
INNER JOIN
    obra ON vivienda.id_obra = obra.ID
where Tipoogia.ID in (
   SELECT tipologia_productividad.id FROM
    partida_tipologia
  INNER JOIN
    partida_productividad ON partida_tipologia.id_partida = 
    partida_productividad.id
  INNER JOIN
    tipologia_productividad ON partida_tipologia.id_tipologia = 
    tipologia_productividad.id
  WHERE
    partida_tipologia.estado=1;
)
```

Ademas no se recomienda hacer subconsutas debido a que son mas lentas.
Hicieron una pregunta sobre el tema hace tiempo que yo mismo conteste y puedes ver aqui: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/143196/qué-es-una-consulta-anidada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/143196/qu%C3%A9-es-una-consulta-anidada)

Comment: Revisa la edición que hizo el OP tiene una duda dirigida a ti